# How can I show all posts of a custom post type from current single post category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type and it have many categories. When I open a single post of this custom post type post, then at the bottom of this custom single post, I want to show 8 posts title, image etc from this single post category.

Comment: OK, great. Are you working on a theme or a child theme? Have you set up a query and a loop to do this? What problem are you running into _specifically_?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in single.php of your theme.

```html
$related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 8, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <ul> 
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?> 
        </li>
    </ul>   
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you  please mark correct to it.